# Install an extension using a third-party application

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote my own installer for my application. In addition to installing the application, I want to install the Chrome extension. How can I do that?

The installer wrote in python. Just.

Extensions are not in the store of extensions of chrome.

Comment: Can you share some more limelight about the issue?

Comment: [Alternative Extension Distribution Options](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions).

Comment: @wOxxOm, it says that the extension should be in the extension store

Comment: It says how it works. There's no other way except for loading the extension in developer mode but that will display a warning in Chrome (except Canary).